# Prometheus eats last decimals zero

Tags: monitoring, metrics, prometheus

I have next metric on my webservice:
app_version{labels} 57.1280

But when Prometheus collect data:
app_version{labels} 57.128

How can I keep whole metric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prometheus works with floats, and both of them are the same value. If you need an exact string you should use a label for this value such as explained in [this blog post](https://www.robustperception.io/exposing-the-software-version-to-prometheus).

Comment: Thank you Brian. I think I can't use labels in this case, because I have some math functions with this versions.